# Saving JSON Facebook results in SharedPref

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to saves Facebook id and facebook usrname in my SharedPreferences on my android app to use it whenever and wherever i want, but logcat returns me "empty"
here is my "Oncomplete" Facebook method:

```
   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {



                                String result = response.toString();
                                SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
                                edt.putString("result", result);
                                edt.commit();
                                Log.i("string","PROVAAAAAA");

                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }
```

i noticed that logcat doesn't writes "PROVAAAAAAA"
And here is my callback method:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
        String id = pref.getString("facebook_id", "empty");
        Log.i("RESULT", id );
        Log.i("RESULT", "***************");

        edt.commit();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [Activity#getPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)) method when what you really want is [PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)). The former is described as being "Activity persistent state", which may be why you're having trouble accessing it.

Try replacing all occurrences of `getActivity().getPreferences(0)` with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())`.

Comment: so what should i do? @roarster